ADF pipeline, source is AZUE SQL and destination CSV in Blob Storage
Actually trying to prepare a azure pipeline(ADF) to get the CDC in Blob storage CSV for 200 tables in Azure SQL, but seems we are able to do for a single table however we want to get a single CSV for every table and having around 200 table in Azure SQL so please assist me to prepare a single file foe a table along with CDC.

are you trying CDC in dataflow? Can you show your pipeline flow?

Hi, this pipeline had lookup activity, forEach loop activity and forEach activity consisted of copying the data from sql to blob
Lookup activity acted as a query where the output was all the rows with $operation == 2
For each would iterate through the result of the lookup and copy all the rows to blob in CSV format

So, it seems like you have an alert system that alerts this pipeline whenever any change is made in your source tables. your only issue is writing all tables data to a single file? Correct me if I am wrong?

Correct, the main concern is to have all the CDC and Incremental data in a single file.


Correct, the main concern is to have all the CDC and Incremental data in a single file

The copy activity will overwrite the target file every time with new data. So, using copy activity, you might not get your requirement done.
You can use Dataflow instead of copy activity. First, use copy activity before the for-loop. Copy only the first table (first row from lookup) from source table to target file. This will create the target table. After this copy activity, use for-each.
In the for-each, change the expression like taking from the second item to last in the lookup output array. Use skip() to skip the first item from the lookup output array.
Inside For-Each, take dataflow activity. Create a dataflow with 2 sources. Source1 is your target table dataset and Source2 is your source table dataset.

Next, add a Union transformation to both these two sources and do the union By name.

In the sink, add your target file dataset and go to sink settings, set the File name option to Output to single file. Give your target file name in the Output to single file like below.

You can provide values for the source dataset parameters in the Dataflow activity. Here, I have given a sample value. In your case give your value as per the for-loop.

The first copy activity will create your target file. Then, in each iteration of for-loop the dataflow will union each previous iteration file data with current source table data and copies it to the same file. In this way, after the end of for-loop, your target file will contain all the data from your source tables.

Are we trying to capture every table records in a single file or preparing a single file for each SQL table as I would be in call till late night so thought to raise the query you to get  clarification about this.

First of all thanks to share the resolution with me, would be sharing the updates after having a try on the same, just wanna to know, are we capturing all the tables data in a single file or making a separate file for each table of Azure Sql along with modified or changed records. as i would be in call till late night so just wanna to get clarification about it.

No, it will copy all records to a single target file at the end of the for-loop. Read the last line of my answer to understand the concept.

But our motive is to create a separate file for each Azure SQL table and if any modification performed on the source table then the same update insert or delete operation will be apply on belonging blog storage CSV file. if we would try to capture all the tables records in a single file then it would be an issues as every SQL table must have different structure. is this making sense?

I am still looking for the solution, Let me explain again.

I am still looking for the solution, Let me explain again. following are the steps which we followed: 1. Enabled the CDC in Azure SQL 2. Used Change Data Capture in ADF and have the destination folder in Azure Blob Container, and when we run the CDC through ADF then system is capturing all the made changes in destination folder like if I deleted a records than a file with delete entry and if you performed delete, update and insert in single session then a single file with all the operations, now How can I feed the same logs file in delta tables where I can see the final result set with changes

Apologies for the late reply. I saw, you have raised a new question regarding this, I will try to update there.

Thanks for your response, and no need to apologies its okay delay can happen. Did you get my concern where we are stuck and not able understand the issue. if not then would try to explain again. is there any way where we can have talk over the call in case required.
